Is it possible to set NUMA node binding for each worker while running a fastapi instance with 4 workers?
Is it possible to bind each worker(uvicorn) to a numa node while trying to run a fastapi appln. using uvicorn workers and gunicorn server?
Tried performing membind using numactl with post_fork(hook) in gunicorn config file but numactl doesn't seem to work for already running processes..is there any other way to do this
